# Javascript forEach / .map shows undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

When I run this code, in Chrome's sources tool in inspect, it says number = undefined for line 7 (groceryList.forEach(function(number) {). The arguments are being passed properly and if I do a console.log for each item it shows properly. Having the same issue with the commented out .map section that does the same thing as foreach.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```js
//BUSINESS LOGIC

var alphabatize = function(item1,item2,item3,item4){
  groceryList = [item1,item2,item3,item4];
  groceryList.sort();
  upperGroceryList = []
  groceryList.forEach(function(number) {
    console.log(number);
    upperGroceryList.push(number.toUpperCase());
  });
  /* upperGroceryList = groceryList.map(function(grocery) {
    console.log(grocery);
    return grocery.toUpperCase();
  }); */
  return groceryList;
  return upperGroceryList;
};



// FRONT END

$(document).ready(function() {
   $("form#items-form").submit(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var item1 = $("input#item1").val();
     var item2 = $("input#item2").val();
     var item3 = $("input#item3").val();
     var item4 = $("input#item4").val();
     alphabatize(item1,item2,item3,item4);
     upperGroceryList.forEach(function(currentItem) {
       $("#display-list ul").append("<li>" + currentItem + "</li>");
     });
   });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two return statements from a function. Instead you can return an object contained both arrays like:

```
  var obj = {
        groceryList : groceryList,
        upperGroceryList : upperGroceryList
  };

  return obj;
```

Then you can use this way:

```
  var arr = alphabatize(item1, item2, item3, item4);

  arr.upperGroceryList.forEach(function(currentItem) {
   $("#display-list ul").append("<li>" + currentItem + "</li>");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several things here. Yyour function variables are never defined.

```
var alphabatize = function(item1,item2,item3,item4){
                     var groceryList = [item1,item2,item3,item4], //use comma to define more than one with one var statement. 
                         upperGroceryList = []; //end var declaration with semicolon.

                         groceryList.sort();

                         groceryList.forEach(function(number) {
                                       console.log(number);
                                       upperGroceryList.push(number.toUpperCase());
                         });
  /* 
  You cannot have return more than once in a function.
  return groceryList;
  return upperGroceryList;
  */
};
```

also your upperGroceryList forEach function should be inside of the alphabatize function.

so the full alphabatize function should look like this.

```
var alphabatize = function(item1,item2,item3,item4){
                            var upperGroceryList = [],
                                groceryList = [item1,item2,item3,item4];

                            groceryList.sort();

                            groceryList.forEach(function(number) {
                                console.log(number);
                                upperGroceryList.push(number.toUpperCase());
                            });

                            upperGroceryList.forEach(function(currentItem) {
                              $("#display-list").append("<li>" + currentItem + "</li>");
                            });
                          };
```

and our submit function looks like this.

```
$(function(){
          $("#items-form").submit(function(event) {
              event.preventDefault();
              var item1 = $("#item1").val();
              var item2 = $("#item2").val();
              var item3 = $("#item3").val();
              var item4 = $("#item4").val();
              alphabatize(item1,item2,item3,item4);

          });

});
```